# Globbing a bunch of .pkl files into one, then converting to .fbx (on Windows)

Tags: ffmpeg, glob, fbx

I'm experimenting with the beautiful [frankmocap](https://github.com/facebookresearch/frankmocap), feeding a video and getting a quite accurate hands and body tracking. This tool also outputs a .pkl file (which I'm not familiar with) for each frame.

I'd like to convert these files into a usable 3D file but 1. I've discovered I can't use glob.h with ffmpeg on Windows and 2. I cant' get them converted in .fbx.

Along with frankmocap, I've tried [VIBE](https://github.com/mkocabas/VIBE/) but I still end up with the same problem.
Using miniconda3.

I hope someone can help me! Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is a free addon for blender that does this job. I made this addon, but unfortunately, I can´t explain how it works. It´s been a long time. 
https://github.com/carlosedubarreto/b3d_mocap_import

For the addon ready to use in blender, you can use the gumroad link (also for free)
https://carlosedubarreto.gumroad.com/l/mocap_import

Answer (score -1):

Someone has taken a useful script made for VIBE and adapted it to work with FrankMocap keypoints.

The script takes a folder of PKL frames generated by FrankMocap and then uses Blender to animate them into an FBX rig. It doesn't currently include the hands though, which is something I'm currently trying to solve in it myself (and how I found your question).

Link to the script: https://github.com/facebookresearch/frankmocap/files/5750266/fbx_output_FRANKMOCAP.zip

Comment: Welcome to SO! Instead of adding an external link or downloadable to the answer, please add the code that answers the question, Thanks~